# Как позиционировать модальные окна непосредственно над элементами их вызывающими?

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap, позиционирование

Есть сетка `bootstrap` с модальными окнами. Как позиционировать их так, чтобы они всплывали не стандартно по центру экрана каждый раз, а непосредственно над элементом их вызвавшем.

Демонстрация
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Код:**

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
      <div>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nesciunt eius qui, eveniet incidunt expedita officiis est facere non dolorem cum aut maxime recusandae repellendus, voluptas similique repudiandae illum repellat velit.</p>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open modal</button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nesciunt eius qui, eveniet incidunt expedita officiis est facere non dolorem cum aut maxime recusandae repellendus, voluptas similique repudiandae illum repellat velit.</p>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open modal</button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nesciunt eius qui, eveniet incidunt expedita officiis est facere non dolorem cum aut maxime recusandae repellendus, voluptas similique repudiandae illum repellat velit.</p>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open modal</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
      <div>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nesciunt eius qui, eveniet incidunt expedita officiis est facere non dolorem cum aut maxime recusandae repellendus, voluptas similique repudiandae illum repellat velit.</p>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open modal</button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nesciunt eius qui, eveniet incidunt expedita officiis est facere non dolorem cum aut maxime recusandae repellendus, voluptas similique repudiandae illum repellat velit.</p>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open modal</button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nesciunt eius qui, eveniet incidunt expedita officiis est facere non dolorem cum aut maxime recusandae repellendus, voluptas similique repudiandae illum repellat velit.</p>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open modal</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <!-- The Modal -->
  <div class="modal" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">

        <!-- Modal Header -->
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Heading</h4>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        </div>

        <!-- Modal body -->
        <div class="modal-body">
          Modal body..
        </div>

        <!-- Modal footer -->
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что-то вроде такого: (класс `modal__positioned` еще и на тот случай, если эту модалку где-то еще используете)

```js
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function(event) {
  var modal = $(this).find(".modal-dialog");
  var button = $(event.relatedTarget);

  if (button.hasClass("modal__positioning")) {
    modal.addClass("modal__positioned");

    var top = button.offset().top - modal.outerHeight() - 10 - $(window).scrollTop();
    top = top > 0 ? top : 0;
    modal.css("top", top);

    var left = button.offset().left - 20;
    left = left > 0 ? left : 0;
    left = (left + modal.outerWidth()) < $(window).width() ? left : ($(window).width() - modal.outerWidth() - 10)
    modal.css("left", left);

  } else {
    modal.removeClass("modal__positioned");
  }
})
```

```css
.modal.show .modal__positioned {
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
      <div>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nesciunt eius qui, eveniet incidunt expedita officiis est facere non dolorem cum aut maxime recusandae repellendus, voluptas similique repudiandae illum repellat velit.</p>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary modal__positioning" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open modal</button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nesciunt eius qui, eveniet incidunt expedita officiis est facere non dolorem cum aut maxime recusandae repellendus, voluptas similique repudiandae illum repellat velit.</p>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary modal__positioning" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open modal</button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nesciunt eius qui, eveniet incidunt expedita officiis est facere non dolorem cum aut maxime recusandae repellendus, voluptas similique repudiandae illum repellat velit.</p>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary modal__positioning" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open modal</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
      <div>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nesciunt eius qui, eveniet incidunt expedita officiis est facere non dolorem cum aut maxime recusandae repellendus, voluptas similique repudiandae illum repellat velit.</p>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary modal__positioning" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open modal</button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nesciunt eius qui, eveniet incidunt expedita officiis est facere non dolorem cum aut maxime recusandae repellendus, voluptas similique repudiandae illum repellat velit.</p>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary modal__positioning" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open modal</button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nesciunt eius qui, eveniet incidunt expedita officiis est facere non dolorem cum aut maxime recusandae repellendus, voluptas similique repudiandae illum repellat velit.</p>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary modal__positioning" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open modal</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <!-- The Modal -->
  <div class="modal" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">

        <!-- Modal Header -->
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Heading</h4>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        </div>

        <!-- Modal body -->
        <div class="modal-body">
          Modal body..
        </div>

        <!-- Modal footer -->
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: спасибо, еще есть вариант с использованием 
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/popovers/
и указанием `html` в его свойствах. Пример здесь - http://jsfiddle.net/J7nDz/5/